# Renting a velomobile outside the Netherlands

Tags: recumbent

I have seen a few questions on this site and a few more answers which are about Velomobiles.
Several of them show that the asker or answerer has clearly no experience whatsoever with velomobiles and while I would like to tell them to rent one for a day, I am not sure it is even possible in most of the world.

I know that with the bigger sellers of velomobiles in the Netherlands you can arrange to get a test ride which is longer than a normal one, say a whole day, for a small fee which will be returned if you buy from them, even though they do not usually publish the option on their websites.

Are there shops like that or other places to rent a velomobile 'anywhere in the world'?  I will be happy with one location, lists not needed.

Comment: I'm not sure how this isn't a shopping question?

Comment: It might be, but over on Travel Stack Exchange this kind of looking for a location where something is available is not seen as 'need to be closed' as it is not looking for prices but for hard to find services.

Comment: If not a shopping question, it is probably too broad. The world is a big place, most people won't travel more than a few tens of miles to test ride a velomobile. The list would be too long to maintain under Q&A format, or so short it was useless to 99% of the audience.

Comment: I think you underestimate the distance people are willing to go for a test ride, but it is indeed a wild shot at finding places where test rides are possible at all. (In the Netherlands it is common to drive up to 2 hours for a test ride, were we do not usually drive long distances at all. In the USA I expect people wanting to drive half a day or so.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, velomobiles are still a niche product. There are possibly other sites where such a question might get a better response.

https://www.bentrideronline.com (mainly U.S.???), under the forums > specialty discussions > velomobiles has a community that is pretty open, and your inquiry about a test ride might generate responses there.

But you are in Europe, no? Perhaps https://www.velomobilforum.de is a better site... Netherlands and Germany are the main suppliers I know of 'across the pond'.